# Disable button if input is invalid

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular2-template

I have a very long form, but I'd like to disable a specific button (on the template, I don't wanna do it on the component) only if a specific field is empty or has some validation errors, this is a sample of my form:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="email" #email="ngModel" name="my_email" type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <span *ngIf="email.errors?.required">
      This field is required
    </span>
  </div>
  <button [disabled]="myForm.email.errors?.required">Some action</button> 
</form>
```

I don't need to have a full valid form to disable that button, I just wanna check based on the value of that specific input.

How can I do it? what am I missing?

Comment: `[disabled]="myForm.get('email').errors?.required"`. For syntax issues, consider reading [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

Comment: @trichetriche already tried that, and getting the following error => `ERROR TypeError: jit_nodeValue_4(...).get is not a function`

Comment: Why do not you use `email.errors?.required` on the disabled property?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Rename the template variable #email to #emailInput or any name different from 'email' which is the name of a model property..

```
<input [(ngModel)]="email" #emailInput="ngModel" name="my_email" type="text" class="form-control" required>
```

2 - Use the template variable #emailInpunt in the disabled property of the button and in the span which shows the erros.

```
<button [disabled]="emailInput.errors?.required">Some action</button>

 <span *ngIf="emailInput.errors?.required">
    This field is required
 </span>
```

The full code:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="email" #emailInput="ngModel" name="my_email" type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <span *ngIf="emailInput.errors?.required">
      This field is required
    </span>
    <button [disabled]="emailInput.errors?.required">Some action</button> 
  </div>
</form>
```

Try it on the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-disable)